# Best place to execute bash command after sudo su / login for all users?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, login, prompt

I am using turnkeylinux LAMP server which is debian based.  When I log in, my shell is basically just $ and no colors, no dirname, just very basic. I have to use the bash command which then initializes everything so i have colors, vim is correct, the path is showing in terminal etc.

I have to do this every time I sudo su into another user.  Is there a master place i can change to execute the bash command whenever i login or user su?

My login 'typing' is this.

```
type myusername
type mypassword
type bash <- so when i exit from su, i know i'm really back. Why can't this auto run?
type sudo su developer
type bash <- again so i know where i am. Auto run this command after the su
```

Its just a small annoyance i cannot seem to figure out.

Thanks.

Comment: How about just setting bash as *your* login shell, then invoking su with the `-m, -p, --preserve-environment` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login shell is likely `/bin/sh`, check with `getent passwd username`. (Last field on the line.) You can change it with `chsh`, either without arguments so it'll ask what you want, or with something like `chsh -u user /bin/bash`. Same for the other account. `chsh` will ask for your password unless you're root.

`sudo su` is redundant, since both `sudo` and `su` are meant for elevating privileges. Consider just `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` (depending on if you want a login shell or not, it'll affect which startup files are read).

If you want to run something else when starting a session `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile` should work for login shells (i.e. when logging in with SSH or with `sudo -i`). ([Gory details here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html))

Comment: That was it. My shell was /bin/sh not /bin/bash. I used chsh -s /bin/bash on my environment, but it now uses the correct shell.  Thanks.